# Setting gmail to sync / push / notify on wifi only?

Tags: wi-fi, gmail

I have a droid mini that is running 4.2.2 and I want gmail to only sync automatically on WIFI only; never on 4g / network / whatever. How do I do this without rooting the phone?
When I first bought the phone, gmail allowed me to chose to sync on wifi only (and by sync, I mean that it would notify me of new emails and download them or what not on wifi only). This is how it was originally set up. I work for a local cable company and this was great. I know this is how it was originally set up because 1) I set it up that way and 2) when I setup up new internet connections in customer's homes, I would use the wifi on my phone to verify that their internet was working. As soon as the wifi would connect I would usually hear my phone announce I had emails, letting me know the wifi was connected.
Then today, I was having an issue with Google play store. I took my phone into Verizon where they claimed to only have 'soft reset' the phone. Now, not only does gmail download / notify /syn (whatever) whenever it wants but the setting for wifi only is completely gone. I distinctly remember something like 'sync on wifi only' or 'push on wifi only' or something like this. I assume there has been some update or something recently and I have no idea how to check this. I would, however, be happy to uninstall the update if i could get it to work on wifi only again. 

So long story short, how the hell do I get gmail to 'whatever' on wifi only without rooting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an app like Llama or Tasker to activate sync only when on WiFi. If you turn off sync, that also turns off syncing of your calendar/contacts/tasks et al in your Google account.

The Gmail app should have an option to only download attachments via WiFi within your specific account options.

Comment: I would definitely recommend Tasker. IF you google around you'll find some good tutorial videos as Tasker is not super easy to figure out. However, once you do, you're in automation haven!